# WildFly 10 AMQ119032: User does not have permission CREATE_NON_DURABLE_QUEUE on address

Tags: javascript, websocket, wildfly, stomp, activemq-artemis

Im using WildFly 10.1..0.Final and I want connect a JavaScript client using STOMP over WebSocket.  I'm using stomp.js.  WildFly include Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 1.1.0.wildfly-017.

First I added a user called "myguest" using add-user.bat. This user is an "Application User".

Next, I tried many different ways of configure a topic and security setting.
Please check the diferent way that I tried to configure the Topic. Neither worked.

I try to create the "jms.topic.chat" topic, and some variants. Don't work.

My standalone-full.xml is:

```
   ...
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                <role name="myguest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <security-setting name="jms.topic.chat">
                <role name="myguest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true" manage="true"/>
                <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true" manage="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <security-setting name="topic.chat">
              <role name="myguest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true" manage="true"/>
              <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true" manage="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <security-setting name="jms.topic.chat2">
              <role name="myguest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true" manage="true"/>
              <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true" manage="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <security-setting name="topic.chat2">
              <role name="myguest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true" manage="true"/>
              <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true" manage="true"/>
            </security-setting>

            <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>

            <!-- I create it for Websocket -->
            <remote-acceptor name="websocket-stomp" socket-binding="netty-ws"/>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <jms-queue name="chat" entries="java:jboss/exported/topic/chat"/>
            <jms-queue name="chat2" entries="java:jboss/topic/chat2"/>
            <jms-queue name="chat3" entries="java:/topic/chat" durable="false"/>
            <jms-queue name="chat4" entries="java:/topic/chat4"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>

    ...

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>

    <!-- This is created for me:         -->
    <socket-binding name="netty-ws" port="61614" fixed-port="false"/>


    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

This is the HTML client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>STOMP over Websockets to HornetQ</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      .connectionconfig input {
        width: 100%;
      }

    </style>


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/sockjsclient/dist/sockjs-1.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/stomp/stomp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var idClient = 1;          // 1,2,3,...
            var clientName = "cliente"+idClient; // cliente1, cleinte2, cliente3, ...


            var destination = $('#destination').val();

            var stompClient = null;

            function connect() {

                var url = $('#connect_URL').val();
                var login = $('#connect_loging').val();
                var password = $('#connect_password').val();
                destination = $('#destination').val();

                console.log(url+" "+login+" "+password+" "+destination);
                stompClient = Stomp.client(url);

                //stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                stompClient.connect(login,password, function(frame) {
                    setConnected(true);
                    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);

                    stompClient.subscribe(destination, function(messageOutput) {
                      if (messageOutput.body) {
                        showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
                      } else {
                        console.log("got empty message");
                      }
                    });



                });
            }

            function setConnected(connected) {
                document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
                document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
                document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility
                  = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
            }

            function disconnect() {
                if(stompClient != null) {
                    stompClient.disconnect();
                }
                setConnected(false);
                console.log("Disconnected");
            }

            function sendMessage() {
                var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
                var text = document.getElementById('text').value;

                stompClient.send("/app/chat.private", {},
                  JSON.stringify({'from':from, 'text':text}));
            }

            function showMessageOutput(messageOutput) {
                var response = document.getElementById('response');
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
                p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(messageOutput.from + ": "
                  + messageOutput.text + " (" + messageOutput.time + ")"));
                response.appendChild(p);
            }



            $( document ).ready(function() {
              // E.G. Cliente 1, Cliente 2, etc
              $("#clientIdSpan").html(idClient);

              disconnect();

              $("#from").val(clientName); // cleinte1, cleinte2, etc..



            });


        </script>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript><h2>Enable Java script and reload this page to run Websocket Demo</h2></noscript>
  <h1>Cliente <span id="clientIdSpan">x</span></h1>
    <div>
        <div class="connectionconfig">
          <dl>
            <dt><label for="connect_URL">Server URL</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="connect_URL" placeholder="ws://..." value="ws://localhost:61614/stomp"></dd>
            <dt><label for="connect_loging">Loging</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="connect_loging" placeholder="User loging: sergio o guest" value="myguest"></dd>
            <dt><label for="connect_password">Password</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="connect_password" placeholder="User passwor" value="myguest"></dd>
            <dt><label for="destination">Destination</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="destination" placeholder="Destination" value="jms.topic.chat"></dd>
            <dt><label for="from">Nickname</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Choose a nickname"/></dd>
          </dl>

        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
            <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">
                Disconnect
            </button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="conversationDiv">
            <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Write a message..."/>
            <button id="sendMessage" onclick="sendMessage();">Send</button>
            <p id="response"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The console output of Chrome is:

```
Opening Web Socket...
stomp.js:145 Web Socket Opened...
stomp.js:145 >>> CONNECT
login:myguest
passcode:myguest
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
session:-109518014
server:ActiveMQ-Artemis/1.1.0.wildfly-017 ActiveMQ Artemis Messaging Engine
heart-beat:10000,10000

connected to server ActiveMQ-Artemis/1.1.0.wildfly-017 ActiveMQ Artemis Messaging Engine

Connected: CONNECTED
heart-beat:10000,10000
server:ActiveMQ-Artemis/1.1.0.wildfly-017 ActiveMQ Artemis Messaging Engine
session:-109518014
version:1.1

>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:jms.topic.chat


<<< ERROR
message:AMQ339016\c Error creating subscription sub-0
content-type:text/plain
content-length:102

AMQ119032: User: myguest does not have permission='CREATE_NON_DURABLE_QUEUE' on address jms.topic.chat
```

I'm getting this error in the console WebBrowser:

```
<<< ERROR
message:AMQ339016\c Error creating subscription sub-0
content-type:text/plain
content-length:102

AMQ119032: User: myguest does not have permission='CREATE_NON_DURABLE_QUEUE' on address jms.topic.chat
```

I don't understand why is ignoring the create-non-durable-queue="true" flag configured for the "jms.topic.chat" pattern.

I don't found information in internet, about the AMQ119032 error. And the way that WildFly 10 mannage it XML configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I found what was the problem, when you create the Application user, you need add the groups at what the user own. The problems is that "add-user.bat" script call it as "groups" and in the messaging ActiveMQ call it as "role".
When the "add-user.bat ask about thegroups do you want this user to belong to writte for example "guest".

**What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[  ]: guest**

This worked for me for the momment.

```
What type of user do you wish to add?
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties)
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a): b

Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'ApplicationRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : myguest2
Password recommendations are listed below. To modify these restrictions edit the add-user.properties configuration file.
 - The password should be different from the username
 - The password should not be one of the following restricted values {root, admin, administrator}
 - The password should contain at least 8 characters, 1 alphabetic character(s), 1 digit(s), 1 non-alphanumeric symbol(s)
Password : myguest2
WFLYDM0098: The password should be different from the username
Are you sure you want to use the password entered yes/no? yes
Re-enter Password : myguest2
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[  ]: guest
About to add user 'myguest2' for realm 'ApplicationRealm'
Is this correct yes/no? yes
Added user 'myguest2' to file 'C:\WildFlyServer\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\applicationusers.properties'
Added user 'myguest2' to file 'C:\WildFlyServer\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\domain\configuration\application-users.properties'
Added user 'myguest2' with groups guest to file 'C:\WildFlyServer\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application-roles.properties'
Added user 'myguest2' with groups guest to file 'C:\WildFlyServer\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\domain\configuration\application-roles.properties'
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process?
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting conn
ection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? yes
To represent the user add the following to the server-identities definition <secret value="bXlndWVzdDI=" />
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```